# linux ubuntu server 14 is unable to connect to my localhost

Tags: azure, ubuntu-server

please note, i am new to whole Linux system. I started nodejs app on a linux server hosted with azure. The app starts fine via commandline, i can tell it does beacause it connects to my mongoDB and it also sends email template to my mail on start just as i programmed it. but my problem is it does not get connected from localhost via the browser. it runs on port 9000, and when i use firefox to try and open it i get:

```
    unable to connect
firefox can't establish a connection to your server at localhost:9000
```

please what could cause the issue, and how do i go about fixing it ?

Comment: You should set your service to listen to 0.0.0.0:9000, then you can browse the service through localhost:9000.

Comment: @CharlesXu how do i achieve this  ?

Comment: Set it in your service config file.

Comment: @CharlesXu please can you explain better, like i explained i am a learner. where is the service config file located ? what is the path ?

Comment: For example, you  can set ssh port in the config /etc/ssh/ssh_config. I don't know what the service you use. So it needs to set by yourself.